# Как прочесть определенную строку из текстового файла в Python?

Tags: python

Есть файл.txt в нем информация на разных строчках, подскажите, есть ли возможность  получить информацию из конкретной строчки.
Я хочу в программу выводить случайным образом разные строчки из этого текстового

Comment: А вы что-нибудь уже прочитали о работе с текстовыми файлами в Python?

Comment: Что- то читал..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вот попробуй

```
import random
bored = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as fin:
    www = fin.read()
    for string in www.split('\n'):
        bored.append(string)
chance = random.choice(bored)
print(chance)
```

или так

```
import random
print(random.choice(open('file.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()))
```

Comment: `split('\n')` плохая идея -- не всегда у текстовых файлов разделитель строк именно `\n`, может быть и `\r\n`, поэтому делайте просто `bored = fin.splitlines()`, ну и после `chance = random.choice(bored)` или сразу `chance = random.choice(fin.splitlines())`

Comment: мона и так сделать

Comment: Можно, но я бы предпочел закрыть файл на месте (через `with`) :) кст, `'r'` можно не указывать, т.к. режим чтения и так дефолтный :)

Comment: супер. все отлично. думаю  WestSide будет доволен.
Спасибо что указываете путь :)

Answer (score 2):

Читаете строки в список:

```
with open('file.txt') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
```

затем используете его

```
print(lines[i])
```